# Surjective morphism between finite étale schemes of same degree

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $S$ be a scheme, and $X$, $Y$ be two schemes that are étale and finite of same degree $N\geq 1$ over $S$. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a surjective morphism of schemes over $S$. Is it true that $f$ is then an isomorphism of $S$-scheme? If so, could someone please provide a hint or a reference for the proof?

I thank you very much for you help.

Comment: Well, what have you done to try to solve yet?

Comment: I am not conversant with this at all, but I would begin by checking how far we can go at the level of function fields. After all, the degree matches with the degree of function field extension, and that degree is multiplicative in a tower, implying that $f$ gives rise to an isomorphism of function fields...

Comment: If I am not mistaken, $f$ must also be a finite morphism (if we have a sequence $X\rightarrow Y\rightarrow Z$ with the last and the composite arrows being finite, then the first is finite too), whose degree is $1$ by composition (multiplicativity of the degree of field extensions). It follows that if two points $x$ and $x'$ in $X$ have same image by $f$, then they have same residue field (namely the residue field of the common image). I do not know how I could conclude injectivity, and I haven't examined what happens at the level of sheaves either.

Comment: Also, I am still kind of uncomfortable with the notion of étaleness. I do not know clearly what useful result this hypotesis imply.

Comment: If you have already convinced yourself that the degree of $f$ is $1$, then you just need to know that a finite étale morphism of degree $1$ is an isomorphism (can reduce to the case $A\to B$ with $B$ free of rank $1$ over $A$; then it's obvious).

Comment: Oooh right, simply. Thanks to all of you for your hints.